# p2os_urdf pioneer3dx bug

Tags: urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to simulate a pionner like this one (pionner3dx), but when I run the launch file in the package p2os_urdf. pioneer3dx_urdf.launch I get a bugged robot. The wheel is out of place. I think there is a bad definition on the swife joint. Is probably out of place.

I get he following robot in Rviz.

[image: image description]

Paulo.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203618/p2os_urdf-pioneer3dx-bug/) by [End-Effector](https://answers.ros.org/users/7606/end-effector/) on ROS Answers with karma: 162 on 2015-02-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I went into the p2os and copied the pioneer3dx.urdf and I used my own launch file and I got a good result. No problem in the URDF file.

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [End-Effector](https://answers.ros.org/users/7606/end-effector/) with karma: 162 on 2015-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I edited `pioneer3dx_body.xacro`.

I changed the joint types of `base_swivel_joint` and `swivel_hubcap_joint` from `continuous` to `fixed` and it solved the same issues I had concerning the center wheel.

To check, I ran the following commands from the [urdf wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf):

```
rosrun xacro xacro.py `rospack find p2os_urdf`/defs/pioneer3dx.xacro > pioneer3dx.urdf
check_urdf pioneer3dx.urdf
urdf_to_graphiz pioneer3dx.urdf
evince pioneer3dx.pdf
```

Which gave me this:
[image: image description]

I then ran my robot and used the following commands to check the tf tree:

```
rosrun tf view_frames
evince frames.pdf
```

Which gave me this:
[image: image description]

Checking RViz with Fixed Frame set to `odom` gave me this:
[image: image description]

I'll send an email to the maintainer for the p2os repository and see if that is a good fix and have him make updates if they are.

---

Originally posted by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) with karma: 323 on 2015-03-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1